# Oculus Air Link on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wine, windows-10

The download software button on the [Oculus website](https://www.oculus.com/setup/) downloads an .exe file for the Oculus App. I assume a Linux version does not exist. Has anyone managed to:

1. Use the Oculus app on Ubuntu 20.04/18.04?
2. Set up Air Link for Oculus Quest 2 using this app?

I am going to attempt using [Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/index.php) to run the .exe file but wanted to check whether there was a solution for this that I am missing.

**Edit:** [Wine website](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=20173) says the Oculus app .exe is not compatible.

Answer (score 2):

In case it is helpful to others, after more research I have concluded Oculus Air link is currently only supported in Windows. As noted in the "Edit" above, it is not compatible with Wine either.